# Pointer initialization in constructors

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, mfc, dao

I am developing a client-database using MFC and lately I was trying to create a class in order to perform DAO operations (instead of implementing these operations directly at the `CDocument` class). I named this class as `CModel`, and `CDocument` contains it. In order to perform SQL operations using the `CModel` class, I must have access to the `m_session` variable - which represents a database access session - and it can be found in the RecordSet class - which represent one table in a database of mine. Here is a piece of code to better illustrate the situation:

```
#pragma once
#include "MFCApplicationSet.h"

class CModel
{
public:
    CModel(CMFCApplicationSet ApplicationSet);
    ~CModel();
    CMFCApplicationSet * pModelSet;
}

// Model.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication.h"
#include "Model.h"
#include "SQLQuery.h" 
#include "MFCApplicationSet.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

CModel::CModel(CMFCApplicationSet ApplicationSet)
{
   pModelSet = &ApplicationSet //not sure if it is right
}

CModel::~CModel()
{
}


// MFCApplicationDoc.h : interface of the CMFCApplicationDoc class
#pragma once
#include "MFCApplicationSet.h"
#include "Model.h"

class CMFCApplicationDoc : public CDocument
{
protected: // create from serialization only
    CMFCApplicationDoc();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMFCApplicationDoc)
// Attributes
public:
    CMFCApplicationSet m_MFCApplicationSet;
    CModel Model;
}


// MFCApplicationDoc.cpp : implementation of the CMFCApplicationDoc class
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef SHARED_HANDLERS
#include "MFCApplication.h"
#endif

#include "MFCApplicationSet.h"
#include "MFCApplicationDoc.h"
#include "Model.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMFCApplicationDoc, CDocument)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplicationDoc, CDocument)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// CMFCApplicationDoc construction/destruction

CMFCApplicationDoc::CMFCApplicationDoc()
{
    //problem in implementing a instruction to call the Model object constructor
}

CMFCApplicationDoc::~CMFCApplicationDoc()
{
}
```

I've used the debugger to analyse my code flow and I noticed that, from the `CMFCApplicationDoc` constructor (`CDocument`), the constructor from each variable declared in the `CMFCApplicationDoc.h` is initialized. Here's my problem: I've tried to create a `CModel` constructor in order to the `pModelSet` pointer automatically reference the variable `m_MFCApplicationSet` (check the constructor arguments) declared in the `Doc` class, but I am experiencing some trouble in giving this instruction inside the construction of the `Doc` class. Is there a specific or maybe an alternative way to do this? (sorry if this task is kind of elementary, but I am still very newbie in C++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor:

```
CModel(CMFCApplicationSet ApplicationSet);
```

takes object of type `CMFCApplicationSet` by value, meaning that the copy of passed object is created and this copy is then used within its body. When you do the following:

```
pModelSet = &ApplicationSet;
```

you are actually storing the addres of temporary object, which is destructed when execution goes out of the scope of the constructor. If you try to dereference this pointer afterwards, it will produce ***undefined behavior***.

Some might suggest you to pass a pointer, but if you look at your `CModel` class closely, you will see that it has only one constructor and it takes the `PessoaSet` object, i.e. the instance of `CModel` requires the existance of some object of type `PessoaSet`, i.e. you should ***keep a reference, not a pointer***:

```
class CModel
{
public:
    CModel(CMFCApplicationSet& ApplicationSet) : modelSet(ApplicationSet) { }
    CMFCApplicationSet&  modelSet;
}
```

and in the other class that contains instance of `CModel`:

```
class CMFCApplicationDoc
{
public:
    CMFCApplicationDoc() :
      Model(m_MFCApplicationSet) { }

    CMFCApplicationSet m_MFCApplicationSet;
    CModel Model;
}
```

just note that the order, in which members of `CMFCApplicationDoc` are declared actually matters here, since you want `m_MFCApplicationSet` to be initialized earlier than `Model` and the standards (12.6.2 §5) says: *"nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition"*.

Comment: So, what should I do in order to pModelSet stores the addres of a non-temporapy object?

Comment: @Mudkip: Well, possible solution is to change the constructor to `CModel(CMFCApplicationSet* ApplicationSet)` and pass an address to it when invoking it. But you should use a reference here.

Comment: @Mudkip: See my answer now, it should be complete.

Comment: @LihO Your side note is nice convention but should not be enforced with such vigor. Please just prefix it with "I recommend that you use" instead of "Don't use"...

Comment: PascalCase and prefixing classes with an uppercase `C` is the convention to use with MFC. There really is nothing wrong with following this convention for consistency. Recommondations are not very helpful when they come without a rationale.

Comment: @nonsensickle: I removed that side note completely.

Comment: @IInspectable: Well, the fact that this convention is used by MFC just means that he might create a type that is defined within MFC already and make his type name become ambiguous. Anyway, I removed it.

Comment: Thanks, LihO! By the way, these codes should be implemented in the header files? That seems clear to me, although I do not see too much sense in using brackets inside headers instead of cpp files...

Comment: @Mudkip: Keep more complex functionality in .cpp files, but simple constructors and destructors can stay in headers. Also getters & setters... Compiler will try to inline these.

Comment: If you place implementations in header files you usually also want to mark them `inline`. If you don't you're likely going to get linker errors down the road.

Comment: @LihO Thanks and sorry for being finicky, good answer all in all.

Comment: @LihO, I was performing some other tests, and I've tried to reference more than 1 variable in the construction, for example:
class CModel
{
public:
    CModel(CMFCApplicationSet& Set1, CMFCApplicationSet& Set2) : modelSet1(Set1), modelSet2(Set2) 
{ }
    CMFCApplicationSet&  modelSet1;
    CMFCApplicationSet&  modelSet2;
}

I've done something like this... the compiler didn't accuse any error, but apparently there are some inconsistent values (during the programs execution). Is it the way it should be done in order to make multiple references or there is another way?
Thanks in advance!